# Fastest way to retrieve contents of remote file?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have an XML file I need to get the contents of, however I don't need to be able to work with the text, all I need to do is find out if a certain string is found within the returned data so I don't need to use an XML Parser such as `SimpleXML`.

My quesiton is, what's the fastest way to do this as speed is of the utmost importance for this..

I tried 20 operations with `SimpleXML` from my localhost and got an average time of around `34 seconds`; I then tried using `file_get_contents`, and whilst this is a lot faster with an average time for 20 operations of around `20.5 seconds` I would still ideally like to improve the time taken a lot more.

**Edit:** If it matters, the files it will be retrieving will be rather small; max about 30 lines.

Is there anything faster than `file_get_contents` for retrieving the contents of a remote file via http or https?

Comment: I'm interested what some answers are, but it just takes time to open and read a file.  That's likely your slowest bit of this whole process.

Comment: You could use cURL instead.

Comment: @amal that's something I'm considering, though thought it might be slower.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not on your server, try to implement a service that returns the result you need, also try to have a persistent connection/socket for comunication.

Comment: Here you have some examples how to implement a socket in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php , on the remote server you`ll implement the socket server, this will write on the socket each X secconds/miliseconds/trigger action just in case a specific event happens. The client connects to the server and listens for acctions to be triggered.

Comment: I can't control the remote server as it is not under my control; it's a service provided by a third-party.